# Solving for X in an Algebraic equation with both Multiplication and Addition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I haven't done Math in a very long time, or at least something beyond 5th grade stuff, so I'm perplexed by this question.

Given the following formula, solve for X:

Y = X + (X * .0635) where Y = 19892

At first I tried dividing both sides by .0635, but that made Y unreasonably high.  Next, I found an online calculator that gave me the answer, but it didn't show the steps.  I need to be able to see the steps so I understand how the answer was achieved.

Comment: This is a quadratic equation. You'll need the quadratic formula.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I see no exponents in the above.  This is linear.

Comment: It's a first-order equation actually. $X+0.635X=1X+0.635X=1.635X=Y$. Now you can divide both sides of the equation.

Comment: Recognize that $X+(X\cdot .0635) = (X\cdot 1) + (X\cdot .0635)$ which you can factor out a common $X$ (*essentially the reverse of the distributive property: $(a+b)c = ac+bc$*).  Here we have $X+(X\cdot .0635) = X(1+.0635)$

Comment: ... whoops, there is a 0.0635 rather than 0.635 coefficient

Comment: @JMoravitz You're right, I misread the $+$ as $\cdot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful that you have divided $\textit{everything}.$

When dividing you should reach this.

$$y = x + 0.0635x \\ \implies \frac{y}{0.0635} = \frac{x}{0.0635}+x $$

However, the more useful approach in general is to factorise. In particular, here we have that $x$ is a common factor and so $x+0.635x= (1+0.0635)x=1.0635x $

So, $$19892=y=1.0635x \\ \implies x=\frac{19892}{1.0635}=18704.3... $$

Comment: My number was actually .0635, but once I made that adjustment this worked perfectly.  I appreciate the explanation, it helped a lot!